# request Mysql query that bring the name and description with the id number

Tags: php, mysql

I have content.php page that when I click on "More" it must give me the same content with the id number

```
<a class="btn text_3 color_3" href="contentdesc.php?contentid=<?=$content["id"]?>">more</a>
```

the problem is when i Click on More, it direct me to contentdesc.php and gives me the last row in the table by this query:

```
  <?php   
   $select="SELECT * FROM content WHERE id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
                $query=mysql_query($select);
                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                    ?>

                <div class="grid_12">   
                            
                <div class="box3">
        <h3 class="text_4   equal" data-mh="3"><?=$row['name']?></h3>
                                
        <div class="divider"></div>

                                
        <p class="text_8 color_6"><?=$row['description']?></p>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>  
                        
                        
        <?php } ?>
```

Please can anyone help me to bring the content as same id number in the row?

Comment: this is the normal behaviour because you are telling your script that `href="contentdesc.php?contentid=<?=$content["id"]?>"`

Comment: yeah this script is working, I am asking that the content on page "contentdesc.php" is not giving me the row with the same ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query in your `contentdesc.php` page is a little strange.

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

What does it mean?

- `SELECT *`  return all columns
- `FROM content`  from this table
- `WHERE id` where the value of the `id` column evaluates to true.  That is, for every row with a nonzero id.  (Probably not what you wanted.)
- `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` if the table has two or more rows. (Probably not what you wanted).

It's probably incorrect.  You probably need to use this SQL statement instead:

```
  SELECT name, description FROM content WHERE id=DESIRED_ID_VALUE;
```

In php, it will look something like this.

```
 $select="SELECT name, description FROM content WHERE id=" . 
             intval($_REQUEST["contentid"]) . ";";
```

The hyperlink in your first code line generates a URL that looks like this.

```
contentdesc.php?contentid=123
```

The value of `$_REQUEST["contentid"]` comes from that `contentid` [parameter on the URL.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)  [`intval()` turns the value into an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php), to [avoid sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

**Warning**.  The `mysql_` calls you are using are *obsolete* and *insecure*. Please consider using `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead.